# Scrape a webpage using scrapy into tab-delimited format

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy, web-crawler

I would like to scrape and parse the data on these two pages: [here](https://www.drugbank.ca/drugs/DB04899) and [here](https://www.drugbank.ca/pathways) into a tab-delimited format using scrapy. I did these commands:

```
scrapy shell
fetch("https://www.drugbank.ca/drugs/DB04899")
print response.text
```

My two question:
1. for example, for [this](https://www.drugbank.ca/drugs/DB04899) page, when I type:

```
response.css(".sequence::text").extract() 
[u'>DB04899: Natriuretic peptides B\nSPKMVQGSGCFGRKMDRISSSSGLGCKVLRRH']
```

But then when I type:

```
>>> response.css(".synonyms::text").extract()
[]
>>> response.css(".Synonyms::text").extract()
[]
```

But you can see that there are synonyms listed on the webpage and so the output should not be empty. Can someone demonstrate what I'm doing wrong? (I also tried other tags such as synonym, Synonym) etc.

2. When I type: response.css(".targets::text").extract(), the output is [u'Targets (3)']. I'm wondering how I can actually parse the data within this list, but I guess this is related to not using the right tags and question 1 above.
3. This is a vague question/advanced for me at the minute, is it possible to just scrape the whole page in one go, instead of having to know each individual tag? So my output would be a dictionary called 'identification' with Name, accession number, type etc as keys. Then a dictionary called pharmacology with indication, structured indication etc as keys, then another dictionary called interactions, and another called pharmaeconomics etc, one dictionary per page section?
   Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are really no elements with `synonyms` or `Synonyms` class attribute value on the page.

You can get to the synonyms by "going to the right" of the `dt` element with the "Synonyms" text using `following-sibling`:

```
In [2]: response.xpath("//dt[. = 'Synonyms']/following-sibling::dd/ul/li/text()").extract()
Out[2]: 
['BNP',
 'Brain natriuretic peptide 32',
 'Natriuretic peptides B',
 'Nesiritide recombinant']
```